# Using .gitignore doesn't work for my scenario

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following files structure in my server:

```
app/webroot/media/avatars/original/1424293016.png
app/webroot/media/avatars/original/usrimg.jpg
app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb150/1424293016.png
app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb150/usrimg.jpg
app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb350/1424293016.png
app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb350/usrimg.jpg
app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb70/1424293016.png
app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb70/usrimg.jpg
```

I want to exclude all files inside the 'media' directory except 'media/avatars/thumb70' and all it's files.

I can achieve that up to the "avatars" directory but when I go deeper it just exludes the whole "media" directory.

My logic tells me that I should use this .gitignore:

```
# .gitignore file
app/webroot/media/*
!app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb70/*
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring a directory summarily ignores all its content.  If you're going to punch through a wildcarded ignore, the `**` wildcards make for cleaner specs:

```
app/webroot/media/**
!app/webroot/media/avatars/
!app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb70/
!app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb70/**
```

is the way to do it if your project might scale into hundreds of folders, but if you don't like the summary-exclusion feature just shut it off by appending `!*/`:

```
app/webroot/**
!app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb70/**

# whole-directory excludes disabled in the above:
!*/
```

`*` only matches one level so if you're not entirely ignoring a directory you have to use `**` to wildcard all its contents.

It'd be nice if git would take unignoring a path to imply unignores for all the directories along that path, but nobody's taught it to do that yet and unintended consequences are always a worry.

If you want to entirely ignore only specific directories, list those after the `!*/` line.

```
# don't do whole-directory ignores in general but make a special exception for any bin/
!*/
bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows.

```
app/webroot/media/**
!app/webroot/media/**/
!app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb70/**
```

Just remember to include back all directories under the folder `media` first with `!app/webroot/media/**/`. It won't affect the ignoring results alone, since git doesn't track folders, but it can make the `!` rules for the sub-directories be applied.

Answer (score 0):

The man page states (emphasis mine):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file
>     excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is
>     not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that
>     file is excluded. Git doesn't list excluded directories for
>     performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no
>     effect, no matter where they are defined.**

So an ugly solution is:

```
# .gitignore file
app/webroot/media/*
!app/webroot/media/avatars
app/webroot/media/avatars/*
!app/webroot/media/avatars/thumb70/
```